# How to make typescript not crying about compile error when adding custom locator

Tags: javascript, testing, angular, typescript, protractor

I have written a custom locator:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  by.addLocator('automationId', function(value, parentElement) {
    parentElement = parentElement || document;
     var nodes = parentElement.querySelectorAll('[automationId]');
     return Array.prototype.filter.call(nodes, function(node) {
       return (node.getAttribute('automationId') === value);
     });
  });
},
```

but when I try to use it and run:

```
element(by.automationId('auto-id'));
```

the error is:

```
Property automationId does not exist on type IProtractorLocationStrategy
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Meet the same problem with custom matchers. Didn't tried namespace extending (But you defenetely should) so i don't have clean solution for it.

But as hotfix (realy dirty) you can try to access your custom locator thru [''] :

```
element(by['automationId']('auto-id'));
```

Be aware that typescript will think of this as type 'any' so you are loosing benefits of typed objects.